# Render Chart control into html string to append div

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, rendering

I am working on an ASP.net/C# application and I need to do the following:

My question is how can I render a Chart control (the one that comes with the .net4) created dynamically in C# to and HTML string?

What I mean is this:

I am creating a chart dynamically in C#

```
  //CREATE THE CHART
    Chart Chart1 = new Chart();

  //BIND THE DATA TO THE CHART
    Chart1.Series.Add(new Series());
    Chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(xName, yVal);

  //SET THE CHART TYPE TO BE PIE
    Chart1.Series[0].ChartType = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Pie;
    Chart1.Series[0]["PieLabelStyle"] = "Outside";
    Chart1.Series[0]["PieStartAngle"] = "-90";


  //ADD A PLACE HOLDER CHART AREA TO THE CHART
  //SET THE CHART AREA TO BE 3D
    Chart1.ChartAreas.Add(new ChartArea());
    Chart1.ChartAreas[0].Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;

  //ADD A PLACE HOLDER LEGEND TO THE CHART
  //DISABLE THE LEGEND
    Chart1.Legends.Add(new Legend());
    Chart1.Legends[0].Enabled = false;
```

Then I want to Render it as HTML string and return it.

The reason I want this is because I am using AJAX Jquery to call the function that will get the chart as an HTMl string and append it to the 'ChartDiv' div element, in order to display it as a chart

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Service/RPCWebService.asmx/GetHTMLRenderForCountry",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            data: "{'CountryCode':'" + countryCode + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#ChartDiv").append(data.d);

            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
```

Thanks a lot for any help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take a look at the RenderControl method of the chart control.  Here is an example of rendering a control to a string using RenderControl.  http://blogs.x2line.com/al/articles/859.aspx